# Como habilitar ou desabilitar select mais próximo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou usando o Materialize CSS, tenho uma tela onde gostaria que ao Switch ser ativado, o `select` mais próximo se torne ativo para o usuário poder selecionar uma opção, e se o Switch voltar para inativo o `select` também volte ao estado inativo.

**HTML**

```
 <form id="relatorio" name="relatorio" class="col s12">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s4 l4">
     <select id="filtro2" name="filtro2" disabled>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Filtro</option>
       <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
       <option value="2">Opção 3</option>
       <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
     </select>
     <label>Filtro</label>
   </div>
   <div class="switch col s2 l2">
     <div class="switch">
       <label>
         Não
         <input type="checkbox">
         <span class="lever"></span>
         Sim
       </label>
     </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="input-field col s4 l4">
     <select id="filtro" name="filtro" disabled>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Filtro</option>
       <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
       <option value="2">Opção 3</option>
       <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
     </select>
     <label>Filtro</label>
   </div>
   <div class="switch col s2 l2">
     <div class="switch">
       <label>
         Não
         <input type="checkbox">
         <span class="lever"></span>
         Sim
       </label>
     </div> 
   </div>

 </div><!-- /row -->
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".switch").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {

        var filtro = $(this).closest("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked');

        if(filtro == true) {   
            alert("true");
            //$(this).closest('select').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            alert("false");
            //$(this).closest('select').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Já consigo pegar o valor do Switch para saber quando habilitar o `select` e quando desabilitar o mesmo, porém não consigo achar qual o `select` mais próximo para trocar o estado dele.

São vários `selects` que preciso fazer isso, então achar o mais próximo do Switch e trocar o valor dele é essencial.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você conseguirá selecionar o elemento usando:

```
$(this)
.closest('.switch.col')
.prevAll('div.input-field:first')
.find('select')
```

Irá buscar a `div` mais próxima que contenha um `select` e selecionar esse `select`.

Veja funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".switch").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {

      var filtro = $(this).closest("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked');

      var selects = $(this)
         .closest('.switch.col')
         .prevAll('div.input-field:first')
         .find('select');

      if(filtro) {   
         alert("true");
         selects.prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
         alert("false");
         selects.prop('disabled', false);
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="relatorio" name="relatorio" class="col s12">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s4 l4">
     <select id="filtro2" name="filtro2" disabled>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Filtro</option>
       <option value="11">Opção 1</option>
       <option value="2">Opção 3</option>
       <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
     </select>
     <label>Filtro</label>
   </div>
   <div class="switch col s2 l2">
     <div class="switch">
       <label>
         Não
         <input type="checkbox">
         <span class="lever"></span>
         Sim
       </label>
     </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="input-field col s4 l4">
     <select id="filtro" name="filtro" disabled>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Filtro</option>
       <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
       <option value="2">Opção 3</option>
       <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
     </select>
     <label>Filtro</label>
   </div>
   <div class="switch col s2 l2">
     <div class="switch">
       <label>
         Não
         <input type="checkbox">
         <span class="lever"></span>
         Sim
       </label>
     </div> 
   </div>

 </div><!-- /row -->
</form>
```

### Dica

Para comparar valores booleanos, não precisa fazer da forma `if(filtro == true)`. Basta fazer assim: `if(filtro)`.:

```
if(filtro == true) -> if(filtro)
if(filtro == false) -> if(!filtro)
```

Comment: Não consigo entender porque no meu código não funcionou, agora ele parece estar pegando o select correto, exceto se tiver 2 na mesma `<div class="row">`, aí ele seleciona os dois, e o select não ativou em nenhum dos casos, tentei mudar de `.prop` para `.atrr`, mas não obtive exito.

Comment: @Dobrychtop Nunca use `.attr` para alterar valores true ou false porque não funciona... Bom, Me mostre um exemplo de como seria com 2 selects para eu ver como ficaria.

Comment: Resolvi o problema de não selecionar, isso era causado pelo Materialize e como ele faz os `selects`, destruí eles antes de trocar a propriedade e inicializei, agora tenho o problema de selecionar os dois na mesma `row`

Comment: Editei a pergunta com 2` selects` na mesma `row`

Comment: @Dobrychtop resposta alterada.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela atenção @ÐvÐ.

Comment: @Dobrychtop Disponha! Ainda botei uma diquinha no final da resposta. É só atualizar. Abs!